# How to return table multiple rows from a stored procedure and access those values in C# using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to return a table from a stored procedure like inline table value return table but that achieve from stored procedure not a function, so what is the way we can achieve this?

I am trying to use a stored procedure, but it's not working - actually this code is wrong but please provide some proper solution.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spForFilterUpdateSorting 
    @action NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @P1_string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ReturnOutString NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @action = 'SEARCH'
        IF @tableName = 'Student_Details'
            IF EXISTS(SELECT [Name] FROM Student_Details 
                      WHERE [Name] LIKE CONCAT(@P1_string, '%'))    
                SELECT
                    @ReturnOutString = (SELECT [Name] FROM Student_Details 
                                        WHERE [Name] LIKE CONCAT(@P1_string, '%')) // I want to return selected value
            ELSE
                SELECT @ReturnOutString = 'null'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IF @tableName='Student_Details'
            select [Name] from Student_Details where [Name] like CONCAT(@P1_string,'%')
        ELSE
            select null as Name
    END
```

this method will return table, please let me know if it didn't work for you.

Comment: Now this query return set of rows and that set of rows return from sp how? how return table from sp